# jquery tooltip ampersand problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, tooltip

Please, help me to escape ampersand in the tooltips.
When I have `<a title = "M & M">` then it works fine, but if there is no spaces between the words and '&' (e.g. "**M&M**") then it fails and only first part ("M") is shown in the tooltip. The problem is actual for IE only.

Comment: Did you try &amp; for the & character?

Comment: Have a look here: http://www.bytemycode.com/snippets/snippet/406/

Answer (score 7):

Try to use the entity `&amp;` instead of the *raw* `&`.

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references

Comment: Tried. Didn't help. Also tried U0026. Now use this code value.replace(/(\S)&(\S)(.*)/gi, '$1 & $2$3') to insert spaces.